# Batch is printing messages, even though echo is off

Tags: batch-file, registry, echo

I have got a simple code that prints out registry values in a specific key.
The problem is, I'm getting active directory printed out with each iteration of the loop below.

For the record, I use a different key with only 2 DWORD values:
NAME and Test

```
@Echo Off
set SpecialUserRegDir=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows
REG QUERY "%SpecialUserRegDir%" /s | for /F %%f in ('findstr "REG_DWORD"') do ( 
   @echo %%f
   [increment will be here]
)
```

Output

```
C:\User\[username]\Desktop\RegTest>()
NAME

C:\User\[username]\Desktop\RegTest>()
Test
```

I know that this problem disappears if I replace the do block with a signle command, but there will be other code in `do` block, so I can't replace it with singular command.

With that in mind, is there any way to write that REG QUERY command (and the combination after that) without printing out the `C:\User\[username]\Desktop\RegTest>()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try with :

```
@Echo Off
set SpecialUserRegDir=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows
REG QUERY "%SpecialUserRegDir%" /s | for /F %%f in ('findstr "REG_DWORD"') do @( 
   echo %%f
   [increment will be here]
)
```

the pipe and the for turn echo on so you need to echo off the brackets too.

Comment: It's surprisingly simple. Thank you!